# Where can i find a version of javascriptcore that has an iphone-compatible static library?

Tags: javascript, iphone, xcode

I've been searching for a version of javascriptcore that i can build into my iphone app to allow for embedded scripts in my application, but i can't seem to find an iOS ready project that has the settings and files i need.  I've tried getting from the webkit svn, but if i make a cocoa-touch static library and include the relevant files, i get layers of compiler errors that reveal other errors when i resolve them.  The javascriptcore files that apple provides on their website don't come with an xcode project, and copying those files into the xcodeproject provided in the webkit svn checkout still give me compiler issues.  Is there anywhere i can find an iOS project that compiles javascriptcore for easy integration into an iphone app?